# Finding the start of an expression when the end of the previous one is difficult to express

Tags: antlr4

I've got a file format that looks a little like this:

```
blockA {
  uniqueName42 -> uniqueName aWord1 anotherWord "Some text"
  anotherUniqueName -> uniqueName23 aWord2

  blockB {
     thing -> anotherThing 
  }
}
```

Lots more blocks with arbitrary nesting levels.

The lines with the arrow in them define relationships between two things. Each relationship has some optional metadata (multi-word quoted or single word unquoted).

The challenge I'm having is that because the there can be an arbitrary number of metadata items in a relationship my parser is treating `anotherUniqueName` as a metadata item from the first relationship rather than the start of the second relationship.

You can see this in the image below. The parser is only recognising one `relationshipDeclaration` when a second should start with `StringLiteral: anotherUniqueName`

[image: sample parse]

The parser looks a bit like this:

```
block
    : BLOCK LBRACE relationshipDeclaration* RBRACE
    ;

relationshipDeclaration
    : StringLiteral? ARROW StringLiteral StringLiteral*
    ;
```

I'm hoping to avoid lexical modes because the fact that these relationships can appear almost anywhere in the file will leave me up to my eyes in NL+ :-(

Would appreciate any ideas on what options I have. Is there a way to look ahead, spot the '->', for example?

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example certainly looks like the `NL` is what signals the end of a `relationshipDeclaration`.

If that's the case, then you'll need `NL`s to be tokens available to your parse rules so the parser can know recognize the end.

As you've alluded to, you could potentially use `->` to trigger a different Lexer Mode and generate different tokens for content between the `->` and the `NL` and then use those tokens in your parse rule for `relationshipDeclaration`.

If it's as simple as your snippet indicates, then just capturing `RD_StringLiteral` tokens in that lexical mode, would probably be  easier to deal with than handling all the places you might need to allow for `NL`.  This would be pretty simple as Lexer modes go.

(BTW you can use `x+` to get the same effect as `x x*`)

```
relationshipDeclaration
    : StringLiteral? ARROW RD_StringLiteral+
    ;
```

I don't think there's a third option for dealing with this.

Comment: Thanks so much, Mike. Your steer got me on the right track and gave me confidence I wasn't missing another option. All working now!